# Angular 4 Insertar más de un componente dinámicamente

Tags: angular4

Estoy tratando de insertar diferentes componentes en un mismo HTML con Angular.

He visto ejemplos de cómo insertar diferentes componentes de esta forma, pero solo lo hacen con un componente a la vez. En mi caso me es necesario insertar más de un componente en la UI.

La información de qué componentes incluir se conoce en tiempo de ejecución, no compilación. Por ello estoy teniendo dificultades.

¿Alguna idea?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Encarna, bienvenida, por favor, podrías incluir tu código para poder brindar una mejor ayuda? Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Para crear dinámicamente componentes en Angular +5 me creo un servicio:

```
import {
  ComponentFactoryResolver, Inject, ViewContainerRef,
  ApplicationRef, ComponentRef, EmbeddedViewRef,
  Injector, Type, Injectable
} from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ComponentLauncher {

  private _componentRef: ComponentRef<any> = null;

  constructor(
    private aplicationRef: ApplicationRef,
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private injector: Injector
  ) {}

  create<T>(component: Type<T>, props: {[key: string]: any} = {}): ComponentRef<T> {
    // Prepare factory, reference, component element and component root element
    const componentFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
    const componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector);
    const componentElement = (componentRef.hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as HTMLElement;
    const componentRootElement = (this.aplicationRef.components[0].hostView as EmbeddedViewRef<any>).rootNodes[0] as Element;
    // Properties passed to Component
    Object.keys(props || {}).forEach(prop => componentRef.instance[prop] = props[prop]);
    // Attach & Instance Component
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.aplicationRef.attachView(componentRef.hostView);
      componentRef.onDestroy(() => this.aplicationRef.detachView(componentRef.hostView));
      componentRootElement.appendChild(componentElement);
    });
    return this._componentRef = componentRef;
  }

  destroy(): void {
    if (this._componentRef) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this._componentRef.destroy();
        this._componentRef = null;
      });
    }
  }

}
```

Y luego lo utilizo:

```
const AlertComponent = this.componentLauncher.create(AlertComponent).instance;
// Si es necesario, más adelante lo libero del DOM y de la memoria
this.componentLauncher.destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

Al final utilicé lo siguiente y va bastante bien (parent es un objeto del DOM leído con *ViewContainerRef*):

```
var factories = Array.from(this.componentFactoryResolver['_factories'].keys());
var factoryClass = <Type<any>>factories.find((x: any) => x.name === 'NombreComponente');
const factory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(factoryClass);
const compRef = this.parent.createComponent(factory);
```